# Task-Based data service in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I'm trying to write a silverlight app using the await/async 'pattern' (using SL5 and VS11), but I cannot select the 'Generate Task-Based operations' in the service config, is this supposed to be possible (yet)? Can't find much detail on the web (specific to SL)...

Comment: I was able to repro your situation: the entire "Client" section of the Service Reference Settings dialog is disabled for SL projects. You may want to open up a Microsoft Connect issue just to bring it up before VS11 is released.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, so I don't need to admin myself to a mental hospital for this :)

Comment: I've added a MS Connect issue for this, no activity there yet: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/722368/await-async-pattern-in-sl5

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to create manually Task based asynchronous service proxy in Silverlight 5 and Visual Studio 2010.
Works like charm.
I personally prefer to code my contracts and service proxies manually, but if you like to use Generate Service reference you can take a look at [this post - WCF + Tasks](http://arbel.net/2011/06/04/wcf-tasks/).

Comment: How is this related to the await/async functionality brought into VS11? (or Async CTP for that matter?)

Comment: As far as I know you can use async/await syntax with any method that returns Task or Task<T>.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not supported in Silverlight but you can do that yourself, Maybe a portable class library would be another workaround for this.

```
public class MyCServiceProxy
{
    public static Task<ObservableCollection<MyC>> GetMyCs()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ObservableCollection<MyC>>();

        var client = new MyCServiceClient();

        client.GetMyCsCompleted += (s,e) => {};

        client.GetMyCsAsync();

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```